# 4k Display on Ventura Non-Native Resoution

Tags: display, ventura

Before upgrading to Ventura (13.0.1), plugging my 2019 MBP into my external monitor via USB natively displayed the screen at 3360x1890. It still does so on my wife's laptop which is running Monterey.

Now, when I plug in my laptop, the highest resolutions offered to me are 5120 x 2876, which makes all of the UI elements shrunk, or 2560 x 1438, which makes text and icons very blurry.

Is there a known fix for this?

[image: Screenshot of display resolutions]

Comment: Can you **not** setting the resolution lower?

Comment: I can. I think it just makes the UI elements large and doesn't fix the blur issues. Unless I am choosing the wrong resolutions?

Comment: Have you tried Ventura 13.1?